# Get/Count Number of Entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

```
ERP_EMIModelContainer context = new ERP_EMIModelContainer();

...
```

How can I get these? Didn't find out yet -_-
When I have a Entity: Order and Customer, then countresult will be 2 and so on..

**EDIT:**

I'm working with the Entity Framework 4, I need to access the metadata of the Model (thats the diagram, from which I generated a Database).

One Entity = One Table.

I would like to get the number of Entities/Tables programmaticaly from code, (maybe using the contexobject? Dk..)

So if I created a Entity **Customer** and an other: **Order**, the count/result will be 2. Hope is better now..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found it out.

I have to use the contextobject:

```
ERP_EMIModelContainer context = new ERP_EMIModelContainer();
```

and now I do this:

```
int numberOfEntities = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace).BaseEntitySets.Count;
```

btw Thanks for downvoting the question ...

Comment: Don't blame us for downvoting. Blame yourself for writing a poor question that nobody understands.

Comment: There was nothing incomprehensible. People that work with EF know what was meant. Shame on you.